# Using conditional comments with RequireJS to load IE7/8 only jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, requirejs, require

I'm using Require JS in my project which is loading jQuery and some other JavaScript files that are relevant for the entire site and all browsers.

However, I need to use some conditional jQuery on Internet Explorer 7 & 8, I've tried putting this in the head of the page and the script doesn't seem to be able to find jQuery, I'm presuming this is because it's getting loaded before jQuery.

```
 <script data-main="/@ViewBag.ScriptsFolder/main" src="/scripts/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/ie.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Is there any way to rectify this? I'm also trying to load Selectivizr in this way which isn't working because of the same problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use a conditional IE-specific class on the `html` element, then checking for it and loading the IE dependencies inside your existing `main` script. So, the top of the document would look like:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]> <html class="ie"> <![endif]-->
<html>
```

And then inside `main.js`, you could use:

```
if ($('html.lt-ie9').size()) {
    require(['/Scripts/ie'], function(ieScript) {
        // ... do stuff
    });
}
```

You can't use the method you've described because require.js looks for a single `data-main` attribute to specify the 'entry point' - any subsequent calls to `require` should be done in Javascript.

Comment: thanks very much! I've used a variant of this and it works perfectly :-)