# Loading IE dependencies with requireJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I'm relatively new to requirejs. I'm trying to load my IE dependencies through require, but only if the browser is lower than IE9. I'm trying the approach suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/11846837/1954860 for loading the IE dependencies.

The problem is, when this code is loaded, jQuery/$ is not yet defined.
This is the code of my main.js:

```
require.config(
{
    baseUrl: 'scripts',
    paths: {
        // Vendor modules
        angular: 'vendor/angular/angular',
        jquery: 'vendor/jquery',
        domReady: 'vendor/domReady',
        angularResource: 'vendor/angular/angular-resource',
        angularTouch: 'vendor/angular/angular-touch',
        openLayers: 'vendor/openlayers',
        typeAhead: 'vendor/typeahead',
        azimuth: 'vendor/azimuth/module'

        // App modules

    },
    map: {
        // This mapping makes sure noConflict is used for jquery. Use noConflict.js to configure whether or not
        // window.jQuery should remain available. If it is not left available in the global namespace, any jquery
        // plugins that do not use AMD cannot be used without modifying those plugins to be AMD modules.
        // So be warned.
        '*': {
            'jquery': 'noConflict'
        },
        noConflict: {
            jquery: 'jquery'
        }
    },
    shim: {
        angular: {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        angularResource: {
            deps: ['angular']
        },
        angularTouch: {
            deps: ['angular']
        },
        openLayers: {
            exports: 'openLayers'
        },
        typeAhead: {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'jquery' // Make sure the noconflict configuration of jquery doesn't break this extension
        },
        azimuth: {
            deps: ['angular', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'az'
        }
    }
}
);

require(
[
    'angular',
    'app',
    'bootstrap', // This is not Twitter Bootstrap, but our own AngularJS Bootstrap
    'controllers/rootController',
    'services/searchService',
    'directives/ngbkFocus'
    // Any individual controller, service, directive or filter file that you to the app will also need to be added here.
    // This is manual maintenance. Although maybe Yeoman could help.
],
function(angular, app) {
    'use strict';

    app.config(['$routeProvider',
        function($routeProvider) {
            // Define your routes here
        }
    ]);
}
);

// IE8 and below specific scripts
if ($('html.lt-ie9').size()) {
require(['/scripts/ie'], function(ieScript) {
    // ... do stuff
});
}
```

The html-element of the index.html of my app looks like this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>     <html class="ie lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>        <html class="ie lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>        <html class="ie lt-ie10 lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>        <html class="ie lt-ie10><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--><html><!--<![endif]-->
```

So... how would I go about this? Can I do a conditional require call like this? Should I put the require call somewhere else?

Best regards,
Martijn Senden

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, I think you need to wrap it around `require`.

```
require(['jquery'], function($) {
   // IE8 and below specific scripts
   if ($('html.lt-ie9').size()) {
      require(['/scripts/ie'], function(ieScript) {
         // ... do stuff
      });
   }
});
```