# How to write advanced conditions in RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

How to write custom conditions in including JavaScript files using RequireJS?

**Example:1**

```
    if("ontouchend" in document) document.write("<script
    src='/js/jquery.mobile.custom.min.js'>"+"<"+"/script>");
```

**Example:2**

```
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Currently I am using shim and paths. Is there any room to place this. Is it possible?

Comment: might help : [**using-conditional-comments-with-requirejs-to-load-ie7-8-only-jquery**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846747/using-conditional-comments-with-requirejs-to-load-ie7-8-only-jquery)

Comment: Thanks @mithunsatheesh, it was same as Amol has suggested, i was looking for to handle this things inside requireJS  itself. Is there no room to accomplish this? Okay if i agree with your by conditional statements inside HTML itself, what about for my Example:1. How to achieve that? like that some other custom JS Functions. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: As you can see those conditions were in pure javascript and had nothing to do with require. so the problem will reduce to whether you can write the condition in javascript, :). Recommend you to remove algorithm|json tags as they wont serve any purpose on your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a conditional specific class on the `html` element itself, then checking for it and loading the dependencies will be easier in the inside your existing script.

**For Example:**

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]> <html class="ie"> <![endif]-->
<html>
```

And in your script, you could try something like:

```
if ($('html.lt-ie9').size()) {
    require(['/Scripts/ieSpecificScripts'], function(ieScript) {
        // ... do stuff
    });
}else
{
...
}
```

Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: So u mean, i have to maintain separate common.js file for i.e Scripts which contains too many shim and jquery paths tags. Its a big head-ache. And for each html tags if i keep on using multiple tags also not sounds good for me as i can check the browser and its version directly from jquery. Any alternate solutions please :)

Comment: You should really give credit to the person that originally posted this answer, don't you think? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846747/using-conditional-comments-with-requirejs-to-load-ie7-8-only-jquery/11846837#11846837

Comment: @JohnWilliams: Yup you are right. But who knows He answered the same? And moreover, nobody cross checks before answering a question which is *no*t marked as a duplicate question.. *If you feel the question and answer is same/copy/duplicate*. You could mark the question as duplicate linking to original question itself. Not the answer. **Don't You Think So**?? And nobody can write those *if condition* in different ways.. lol.. its syntax..